# How to reuse Setup Project in VS(using .NET 3.5)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I have a Setup Project(msi) in solution for install the App to client side, the process is quite simple: copy dlls(all weak name) to a specific folder, call a .exe file to pop up a Form to collect the configuration(customize) information for different client, then the .exe will write to several XML configuration file, then done.
  Now I need a Hotfix package which I think the logic is the quite similar as the previous installer, so I will not create another Setup Project, I just want to copy the previous project and rename it, but after I done that and ran the new Hotfix package, it always say 'the project already installed on your machine, please uninstall that then retry', so it means the linkage between the installer and the App still there, so How to get avoid that?   or do you have any other suggestions to do the Hotfix on App which similar to mine(all weak name, and there's 2 windows services in installer), but won't impact the uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change [`ProductCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the new setup project properties.